# REST API Security for access only to API

Tags: spring-boot, api, spring-security, key

My spring boot app almost done and one more problem left. I need to implement security part. I wanna make acces to api only by key that will come with request. in URL string, message body or header.It doesnt meter now. I found a lot of different ways, but they use login:password pair, it doesnt interesting for me. Each message have to contain KEY.
It should look like

URL String (Get method)

```
https://api.domen.com/news/today?key='somekey'&'some filters'
```

Body (Post method)

```
https://api.domen.com/news/today?'some filters'
{
    "key": "somekey",
    ...
}
```

Is there suggestion how use only key and verify it?

Answer (score 1):

I would include the token on HTTP Authorization header with the Bearer schema (instead that using a parameter), it is a good practise

```
POST /news/today?p=1 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer 123456
```

If you want to rely on JTW (again a standard practise) you need to verify the incoming token, this is an example using `jsonwebtoken` library

```
 Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
        .setSigningKey(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("SECRET"))
        .parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();

 String subject = claims.getBody().getSubject(); // subject  in the token
 Date date = claims.getBody().getExpiration(); // expiration of the token
```

This example above assumes that the token (set on the HTTP header) has been signed using the same key "SECRET"

```
//We will sign our JWT with our ApiKey secret
byte[] apiKeySecretBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("SECRET");
Key signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(apiKeySecretBytes, signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName());

//Let's set the JWT Claims
JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder().setId(id)
        .setIssuedAt(now)
        .setSubject("subj")
        .setIssuer("issuer")
        .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, signingKey);
```

Here is a good reference https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/10/31/jwts-with-java